# ExpSpace problems whose configuration reachability problems are in P/poly?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, advice-and-nonuniformity

Is anything known about ExpSpace problems whose configuration reachability problems are in P/poly?

> Let $M$ be an ExpSpace machine. 
>   Given two configurations $a$ and $b$ of $M$ (of max length), and an integer $t$,
>   can $M$ reach $b$ from $a$ in $t$ steps?

Note that the length of $a$, $b$ and $t$ are exponentially large in terms of the length of the input to $M$.

So the P/poly machine runs exponential time with an exponentially-long advice string. But it should not be something like $\mathsf{EXPSPACE} \cap \mathsf{EXP/exp}$ (and thus simply EXPSPACE) for obvious reasons.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity but I think it is still not clear what you exactly looking for. What do you really need?

Comment: @Kaveh I just wanted to know how powerful it is. But now I have found it simply contained in $\Sigma^2 \mathrm{EXP}$. The question becomes that, is it equal to $\Sigma^2 \mathrm{EXP}$? But it should not be so interesting now. And sorry for my English anyway.